# Preserve data type of post fields when sending data using PHP and cURL

Tags: php, http, post, curl

I am aware that HTTP POST form data are sent to server-side as string values and that I would have to cast them to booleans or integers and so on.

But my question is : **Is it possible to POST data using cURL whilst preserving the types of values?**

Eg:

The following bit of PHP code prepares PHP array of data, where 'age' is an int and 'optin' is a boolean value and then sends this data to a test script using cURL via POST method.

```
$url = 'http://www.sometestserver.com/test/receive.php';

$data = array (
    'name'  => "Firstname SecondName",
    'age'   => 25,
    'optin' => true
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/xml'));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

And I have the following code on the test script which the above code posts the data to. The script simply reads whatever that comes in to it and var_dumps everything to a text file.

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
$data = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents(time() . ".txt", $data);
```

And the output of that is the following :

```
array(22) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(21) "Firstname SecondName"
  ["age"]=>
  string(2) "25"
  ["optin"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

As you can see, all values were converted to type string, and the boolean true was converted to string "1".

In another test, boolean false is sent as an empty string ''.

**Is there any way of preserving the data type?** 
Maybe by setting a particular curl option? 
or is this not possible at all?

If cUrl ALWAYS convert boolean values to string, are there any hard and fast rules of what values to expect on the other end ? i.e. is bool true ALWAYS going to be string "1" and false ALWAYS going to be an empty string?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is in the way PHP cast primitive types to strings. Its only possible send data as string via HTTP and cURL so php converts non-string values to strings using PHP's type juggling system.

Please take a look at [PHP documentation for how PHP cast non-string values using it's type juggling system](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON to preserve types, but... do you really need it?) you always can convert strings to any type

Answer (score 0):

You can send your data like this, a string is always TRUE unless the value is 0 or empty.

Comment: I do understand that this is how languages like PHP would cast strings to natural data types. But I would like to know the rules that cURL uses when making the conversions because I don't always know which language does the systems that I post data use and how those languages/systems interpret string representations of boolean values

Answer (score 0):

I found that casting the array to an object causes the values to be preserved. Probably because curl converts the object to json when sending and php converts it back into an associative array on the receiving end.

```
$data = (object) array (
    'name'  => "Firstname SecondName",
    'age'   => 25,
    'optin' => true
);
```